# Can not Draw a polygon using Google Map API V2

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I have the following function in which I am trying to draw a polygon with certain Lat Long

```
function AddTile( minLat, minLon, maxLat, maxLon )
        {
            var points      = [];


            points.push( new GLatLng( parseFloat(maxLat),   parseFloat(maxLon)  ));
            points.push( new GLatLng( parseFloat(minLat),   parseFloat(maxLon)  ));
            points.push( new GLatLng( parseFloat(minLat),   parseFloat(minLon)  ));
            points.push( new GLatLng( parseFloat(maxLat),   parseFloat(minLon)  ));               
            var polygon = new GPolygon(points, "#f33f00", 5, 1, "#ff0000", 0.2);
        map.addOverlay(polygon);


    //map.addOverlay(new GPolyline(points,'#8080FF', 8, 0.5, '#8080FF', 0.5));


        }
```

but can not get the polygon drawn on the map. Howevery the Polyline can get drawn which show the lines having the gap among these. 
What I want to know from you is Whether my API for Google maps no longer support drawing the polygon. I am using Google maps API V2. if there is a way for this to sort then describe.
Also if polygon can not be drawn then how can I use new GPolyline() construct to draw the polines without any gap and a background color to eliminate the gaps of lines.
I have tried giving weight a value 10 which makes the lines more solid hence making the non transparent which i don't want.
Please guide.
Thank You

Comment: Why are you using the [deprecated (and turned off) Google Maps Javascript API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/introduction). You _should_ be developing for the [Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics)

Comment: What if we convert to API v3. will the existing architecture that we constructed in V2 work?

Comment: What "architecture"?  The code that you posted so far is a simple port to v3. The two APIs are different enough that it takes work to port some of the functionality, but v3 is supported, v2 is not supported and has no guarantee that it will continue to work.  The v2 wrapper for v3 doesn't (and never will) support the full v2 functionality, it is what it is.

Comment: if we use Polylines. Can we narrow down the gap between lines and can we have a background with opacity in that ?

Answer (score 1):

As *geocodezip* has suggested you should use API v3. Below I have converted your code that used old(deprecated) v2 functions like GLatLng, GPolygon to v3 equivalents. See if it works

```
function AddTile( minLat, minLon, maxLat, maxLon)
{
    var mapOptions = {
                      zoom: 4,
                      center: new google.maps.LatLng( 5.44, 22.67),  // set centre somewhere in Africa
                      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
                      };     
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    var points      = [];
    points.push( new google.maps.LatLng( parseFloat(maxLat), parseFloat(maxLon) ));
    points.push( new google.maps.LatLng( parseFloat(minLat), parseFloat(maxLon) ));
    points.push( new google.maps.LatLng( parseFloat(minLat), parseFloat(minLon) ));
    points.push( new google.maps.LatLng( parseFloat(maxLat), parseFloat(minLon) ));
    points.push( new google.maps.LatLng( parseFloat(maxLat), parseFloat(minLon) ));  // same as your 1st point, // polygons should be closed

    // Draw polygon.
    var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
                      paths: points,
                      strokeColor: '#f33f00',
                      strokeOpacity: 1,
                      strokeWeight: 5,
                      fillColor: '#ff0000',
                      fillOpacity: 0.2
                   });
    polygon.setMap(map);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event){
       alert('whatever you want to do');
    });  // in case you want to do something on user click
}
```